# How can I use React Native from source on iOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a React Native app, and I would like to use a version of React Native from my own Git repo, rather than from a release on NPM.

For Android, there are some [reasonably clear instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-from-source.html) in the upstream RN docs.  I successfully followed those instructions for a small test app and it works great.  I can make a change to the RN code in my clone of the RN repo, rerun `react-native run-android`, and a few seconds later I have the app running with the updated RN code.

But that doc is completely silent about iOS.  It must be possible somehow to do this on iOS too. What am I missing?